# Unable to delete selected cell from UICollectionView while tapping a delete button to delete document from Firestore in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to delete a selected document from Firestore by implementing a `UIButton` in `UICollectionView`. Instead of this I am able delete document from last to first (like if we select a button at top it is deleting last cell).

******Here is my code where I am accessing document reference ID******

datafile Struct

```swift
struct DataFile {
    let FirstName : String
    let LastName : String
    let Dateofbirth : String
    let Gender : String
    let countrydata : String
    let statedata : String
    let homeTowndata : String
    let phoneNumberdata : String
    let telephoneNumberdata : String
}
```

Here is where I am adding documents to Firestore in `EnrollCell.swift`:

```swift
@IBAction func editButtonTapped() -> Void {
    print(FirstLabel.text!)
    print(SecondLabel.text!)
    print(ThirdLabel.text!)
    print(FourthLabel.text!)
    print(FifthLabel.text!)
    print(SixthLabel.text!)
    print(SeventhLabel.text!)
    print(EightLabel.text!)
    print(NinLabel.text!)
    if let FirstLabelText = FirstLabel.text, let SecondLabelText = SecondLabel.text,let ThirdLabelText = ThirdLabel.text,let FourthLabelText = FourthLabel.text,let FifthLabelText = FifthLabel.text,let SixthLabelText = SixthLabel.text,let SeventhLabelText = SeventhLabel.text,let EightLabelText = EightLabel.text,let NinLabelText = NinLabel.text {
        db.collection("userdata").addDocument(data: ["First Name" : FirstLabelText,"Last Name" : SecondLabelText,"Date of Birth" : ThirdLabelText,"Gender" : FourthLabelText,"Country" : FifthLabelText,"State" : SixthLabelText,"HomeTown" : SeventhLabelText,"PhoneNumber" : EightLabelText,"Telephone Number" : NinLabelText,"date" : Date().timeIntervalSince1970]) { (error) in
            if let e = error {
                print("There was a issue in saving data to firestore \(e)")
            } else {
                print("successfully saved data")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    FirstLabel.text = ""
    SecondLabel.text = ""
    ThirdLabel.text = ""
    FourthLabel.text = ""
    FifthLabel.text = ""
    SixthLabel.text = ""
    SeventhLabel.text = ""
    EightLabel.text = ""
    NinLabel.text =  ""
}
```

Document reference ID variable in `FeedCell.swift`:

```swift
let db = Firestore.firestore()
var documentdata = ""
```

Here the function `loadUserData()` where adding new document to `dataFile` in `FeedCell.swift` file:

```swift
func loadUserData() {
    db.collection("userdata").order(by: "date", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        self.dataFile = []
        if let e = error {
            print("There was an issue in retrieving data from Firebase \(e)  ")
        }else {
            if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.documents {
                for doc in snapshotDocuments {
                    let data = doc.data()
                    let documentId = doc.documentID
                    self.documentdata = documentId
                    if let Fnamedata = data["First Name"] as? String,let Lnamedata = data["Last Name"] as? String,let DOBdata = data["Date of Birth"] as? String,let genderdata = data["Gender"] as? String,let countrydata = data["Country"] as? String,let statedata = data["State"] as? String,let hometowndata = data["HomeTown"] as? String,let phnumberdata = data["PhoneNumber"] as? String,let telnumberdata = data["Telephone Number"] as? String {
                        let NewDataFile = DataFile(FirstName: Fnamedata, LastName: Lnamedata, Dateofbirth: DOBdata, Gender: genderdata, countrydata: countrydata, statedata: statedata, homeTowndata: hometowndata, phoneNumberdata: phnumberdata, telephoneNumberdata: telnumberdata)
                        self.dataFile.append(NewDataFile)
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            print(documentId)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here delete button code by creating object from `FeedCell.swift`:

```swift
let feedCell = FeedCell()
@IBAction func btnTouched() -> Void {
    db.collection("userdata").document("\(feedCell.documentdata)").delete(){ err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error removing document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully removed!")
            
        }
    }
}
```

Help with deleting selected cell from Firestore and proper updating in `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Why are you trying to do by let feedCell = FeedCell()

Comment: because I just stored the document reference id in feed cell in a `document data` variable.